# In MVC file structure, what is Views/XXFolder/xxTemplateFile what is XXFolder known as?

Tags: model-view-controller, naming-conventions, file-structure

I'm a bit confused about mvc terminology.

Using the question title as an example, a view corresponds to an action, which means xxTemplateFile would be considered to represent the view.

xxFolder does not represent an area. So could it be a View Collection? or View Container?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could reprisent the controller class and controller method for the related view. (or controller and action with the view being attached to the action).

Using your example: `Views/XXFolder/xxTemplateFile` could be used to indicate that your view, xxTemplateFile which is attached to a controller action of the same name, is inside the xxFolder class.

This would make sense if you consider how routed URLs tend to look `{controller,action,id}`

If this is simply the way you're organising your views then I'd be tempted to just refer to them as View folders or folders.

Comment: Yeah indeed, I think view folders makes sense because it really is a physical layout naming convention and not a logical naming convention.  I was just curious if there is a term for it. :-) Cheers for the answer +1